# Ordering of grouped rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

```
SELECT t1.item_id, t1.item, t1.created, t1.owner, t1.type, t1.fld, t2.tag
FROM items AS t1
INNER JOIN tagged AS t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE tag
IN ('how', 'jkas', 'bodor', 'zimp', 'ctuo', 'sjex', 'kek'
)
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY t1.created DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

How to order items by how many matches they have with IN TAG? I went really deep in manual and I couldn't find the answer and I got lost in stuff I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` and put the results in a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT t1.item_id, t1.item, t1.created, t1.owner, 
      t1.type, t1.fld, t2.tag, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.tag) tagCount
   FROM items AS t1
      INNER JOIN tagged AS t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
   WHERE tag IN ('how', 'jkas', 'bodor', 'zimp', 'ctuo', 'sjex', 'kek')
   GROUP BY item_id
) t
ORDER BY tagCount DESC, created DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Thank you. I am proud of you.

Comment: @user2044390 -- I wasn't even done typing :) Let me know if you have any issues with it -- very untested.  Best of luck.

Comment: Problem appeared #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @user2044390 See edits -- like I said, I hadn't finished typing :) -- That just means the subquery needs an alias (I gave it t).

Comment: @user2044390 -- btw, if this answer helped you out, consider marking it as accepted to help future users of the site.  Good luck.

Comment: It told me I can't accept answer so fast yesterday, so I have to wait. Thank you, you saved me hours and learned me a very useful chunk of information about mysql...